# Tens of gesture recognisers

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

We have this graph , with many points on it, i am talking about more then 200 ( that you can scroll to see).

We would like to add this feature that when a user touch a point he see some view that disappear when he moves his finger back .

It should work also if he slides his finger on the  points, like in `iOS` photos when you move your finger over many images.

1. Is `gesture recogniser` the best for this or there is something better?
2. Adding 200 gestures would create memory pressure ?

thanks.

Comment: no you dont add 200 gesture recogniser.You will add only one. You create a grid kinda custom uiview, and you will track your touch point when u touch and when u drag, and based on it, you will do necessary tasks.

Comment: oh thanks, so stupid i didn't think about it. thanks a lot.